# How to change default date in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I am having a requirement to change default date in bootstrap datepicker to future date as per client request.

when user clicks on datepicker, future date should be highlighted instead of current date
i was trying to use several options. but i am not able to figure it out. 
Help me out if there is any attribute that i need to set

Answer (score 0):

You could set the initial date to view when opening the calendar using `defaultViewDate` option.

https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#id3

You could also limit the calendar between two dates using `startDate` and/or `endDate` options.

Comment: for me the calendar is binding dynamically. i am not having any ID for the calendar to set startdate property